# Getting gcc piped-to-less to properly show colors on the terminal

Tags: terminal, colors, less, error-handling

I'm compiling a file with gcc (actually I'm make'ing, but never mind), which sends some colorized error messages to stderr. So, I do:

```
gcc a.c 2>&1 | less
```

but what I get is lines such as:

```
a.c: In function <E2><80><98>whatever(int)<E2><80><99>:
a.c:11:10: warning: etc etc
```

that is, I see the numeric escape codes rather than the colors.

I tried to follow the advice in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/337640/122798) on SU, but it didn't work for me. Or rather, `ls --color | less` works, but not my gcc command above. What should I do?

Notes:

- I'm connected to this machine via SSH, with `TERM=xterm-256color`
- Without piping through `less`, I do get the colors on the terminal.

Comment: Does `less -R` work?

Comment: @Wildcard: No, in the sense that I get the same thing.

Comment: What if you pipe through `cat`?  Do you still see colors on the terminal?

Comment: @Wildcard: No, I don't. but if I do `cat -v` I notice there are nonprinting characters.

Comment: Okay, that means the problem is with the escape sequences that `gcc` is generating when its output is sent somewhere other than a tty—rather than a problem with `less`.  I don't have a `gcc` man page on the box I'm on right now, but if you search for "color" in your man page you might find something.  Good luck.  :)

Comment: Try `gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always a.c 2>&1 | less -R`.  This will break various tools that depend on parsing the output of `gcc`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: That seems to do it. Make it an answer?

Comment: E2,80,98 E2,80,99 are not colors, they are UTF8 for the 'aesthetic' left and right quotes U+2018 U+2019 gcc likes, but they are uglified by `less` the same way colors would be.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Posting as an answer as requested.

There are two problems here:

- By default `gcc` prints color codes only when the output is a terminal.
- By default `less` doesn't send raw color characters to the terminal.

You can force `gcc` to print color codes by passing it the option `-fdiagnostics-color=always`.  Beware that this will break various tools that rely on parsing compiler errors.

You can force `less` to send color codes to the terminal by passing it options `-r` or `-R`.  The latter is safer, since it only allows codes for actual ANSI colors.

Summing it up:

```
gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always a.c 2>&1 | less -R
```